# Odd duplicate symbol error in C

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, duplicates, symbols

Ok so i have a project, and i have some helper functions which need to be shared in various other files. call it Helper.c /.h , with the corresponding compilation flag to avoid multiple inclusion (#ifndef SymbolName #define Symbolname blah blahblah #endif). Every file has its header file in the following way:

```
#include ....
#include ....
#ifndef __FILENAME_H__
  #define __FILENAME_H__ //in each file(FILENAME is replaced for the current file's name)
  declarations of functions, types, etc.
#endif
```

I have a compare function, called dummyCompare (templates, so when creating a variable of this ADT, you need to supply your own function pointer for it to work, so for some cases i don't need a specific function, just a generic one, so that is what dummyCompare is.
The error i get when compiling is:

```
gcc ./Helper.c ./LinkedList.c ./ABB.c ./AVL.c  -Wall -lm -D DEBUG -g
duplicate symbol _dummyCompare in:
    /var/folders/f2/nghjrbz915vbhjw_1gbb65sm0000gn/T//cc75R4sQ.o
    /var/folders/f2/nghjrbz915vbhjw_1gbb65sm0000gn/T//cc8jQwyE.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

List is used for a non-recursive solution for tree operations in ABB(ABB = BST in spanish)/AVL. Now using Sublime Text 2, i get the following search results for "dummyCompare"

```
Searching 8 files for "dummycompare"

/dir/ABB.c:
   81   if (abb != NULL) {
   82       if (ABB_getRoot(*abb) != NULL){
   83:          list = LL_newList(dummyCompare);
   84           LL_insert(list, 1, ABB_getRoot(*abb));
   85           

/dir/AVL.c:
   67   if (avl != NULL) {
   68       if (AVL_getRoot(*avl) != NULL){
   69:          list = LL_newList(dummyCompare);
   70           LL_insert(list, 1, AVL_getRoot(*avl));
   71           

/dir/Helper.c:
    2  
    3  /****************************************************************************
    4: *                                dummyCompare                                *
    5  *****************************************************************************
    6  *    Retorna si 2 dirrecciones son iguales, necesario para el funcionamiento *
    7  *    de la lista                                                             *
    8  ****************************************************************************/
    9: int dummyCompare(void * a, void * b) 
   10  {
   11   if (a == b) 

/dir/Helper.h:
    4   
    5   int getMax(int a, int b);
    6:  int dummyCompare(void * a, void * b);
    7  
    8  #endif

5 matches across 4 files
```

Thing is i can't seem to understand what is wrong, and why am I getting this error. Checked a lot of other question, and only answer i found was ("use #ifndef ... "), which I'm using

Comment: Silly question, but you're only `#include`ing header files and not `.c` files, right? And your implementation file `#include`s the corresponding header?

Comment: You may have some cruft in your output directory, and you are exposing a bug in gcc or your filesystem. Try deleting all *.o and everything from /var/folders/f2/nghjrbz915vbhjw_1gbb65sm0000gn/T

Comment: Try compiling each *.c file to *.o, then linking. At least it will tell you which 2 object files are conflicting. The autogenerated names `cc75R4sQ` etc mean nothing.

Comment: Please search for "Helper.c" in all your files

Comment: Generally, you put the header guards at the very top and bottom of the header file (after any heading comments at the top), and any includes are inside the header guards.  At one level, it shouldn't matter, but it saves the compiler reincluding the extra headers — a minor (but not wholly negligible) benefit.

Comment: I suggest compiling each of the source files to object code separately, and then linking the object files.  That way, you'll get better file names in the error messages, and you'll have a better insight into which two files define `dummyCompare`.  This is repeating what @MarkLakata said — he gave good advice and please pay heed to it.

Comment: yes Chris, i'm only including header files, and yes every .c includes the corresponding .h file(Helper.c includes Helper.h, and so on).

Comment: Put the include guards before your #include statements perhaps.

Comment: Tried that already, normally when that is the issue, you'll get compilation errors, that something is being redefined, but ty.

Comment: Ok, can some1 please explain me what went wrong? changed the function name, recompiled, and worked, is there any kind of temp files associated to gcc? maybe because .c file were not changed, only header files, they were not being recompiled... don't know really.
Closed terminal, opened a new one, changed names back, recompiled and error appears agains, seems a temp file/cache or something is trolling me.